Teardown Voxel Physics
If we assume that Teardown was made in Unity, how would it be made in a high-level way?
See the game here. I tried some things like breaking each shape down into small voxels, but how do you determine pressure, etc?

It would be difficult to satisfyingly explain how to develop an entire voxel physics solution in the confines of a StackExchange answer — that's a lot to ask of volunteers. You might get more useful answers, faster, if you break your problem down into smaller parts, and ask about one element at a time, with no "etc."

You may also want to go direct to the source and learn from Dennis Gustafsson's developer blog, GDC presentations, social media posts, and so on to get an overview of the techniques he uses. Then you can edit your question to focus on one part that you need help with after taking in all the information that's already available.

The voxel physics in Teardown are completely custom code, not using any of Unity's built-in physics engines, so if you want to go that route, expect to be writing it from scratch. This frees you from tailoring things to Unity, so you can learn from any voxel physics resources your searches turn up, including existing answers about implementing pressure in a grid-based simulation.
